# Is it possible for a bluetooth dongle to receive audio input from two different devices at once?

Tags: bluetooth

I have a project idea which involves a bluetooth dongle that has to accept audio input streams from two different devices at the same time. I don't know if that's possible, so would it be possible to have a "slave" and "master" setup where if the "master" is playing audio then that "slave" input is silenced?

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, yes. There's no reason why 1 or more things cannot be paired.

Remember though the bandwidth more than halves (obvious) and will be degraded if they're sending audio at the same time quite severely. I wouldn't recommend it in practice

Comment: It not possible to stream audio from two separate devices to one Bluetooth master. Its not a bandwidth problem just a protocol restriction. Please consider checking technicalities before posting untested answers.

Comment: @ppumkin there's no technical reason why not, and looking at the source code for the driver there is no implementation reason as to why not. I can look into doing it virtually, that's as near as I can get.

Comment: It will require low level Bluetooth control though.. not something that any SDK offers out of the box.

Comment: @ppumkin there's no technical reason why you couldn't. The limitation is bandwidth only, as I said. If there is sufficient bandwidth for the data but the protocol takes too long to switch devices a bigger buffer could be used. As I said in my answer, there's no technical limitation.

Comment: @ppumkin I consider drivers I can modify as 'out of the box' BTW. I smell a windows user :P

Comment: Your nose will take you to good places. I tried developing an app with Bluetooth on Android and Linux and it was pure hell to me. If you know how to do things like that in Android for example, I know somebody that needs a good dev :)

Comment: @ppumkin last comment (I don't want to spam ya) 'requiring low level control' is often required for projects like this. If you want to be able to do what the OP wants you're kinda expected to get your hands dirty.

Comment: Yea no worries. I understand that low level is required... I wonder if the OP will be able to get his hands dirty. I am pretty seasoned developer.. and Bluetooth protocols just broke me down.

Answer (score 1):

You can pair a master to 7 slaves in one piconet, but in a time interval a master is only connected to one slave. So actually you can not accept input streams at same time. But since Bluetooth does frequeny hopping very very fast, with a proper setting it can accept from one then accept from other then other again, but I don't know if it would be efficient in terms of quality since some of the data might be neglected.

Some sources : [Bluetooth Essentials for Programmers](http://read.pudn.com/downloads166/ebook/757380/bluetooth_essentials_for_programmers.4272206415.pdf) , [How Bluetooth works](http://ccm.net/contents/69-bluetooth-how-it-works)

Comment: This is correct. Only one stream at a time. You can however stream from one device to two Bluetooth slaves "stereo" function but requires allot of code work.